# Laravel: Reactivating listeners after flushEventListeners()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have some functionality that is being enacted by my model's event handler that I need to prevent from firing under a specific circumstance.

```
protected static function bootLogSubject()
{
    static::created(function ($subject) {
        $subject->logContent('create', Auth::user());
    });
```

I am aware that I can use `flushEventListeners()` to stop the event firing.  This works fine, but is it possible to switch the listeners back on again (unflush? bind?) once I have finished what I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
Model::boot();
```